# stream a certificate to stdout to download it in php

Tags: php, binary, download, certificates, hexdump

**Related Questions :**

- [when downloading certficate binary data , result is invalid certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17207279/when-downloading-certficate-binary-data-result-is-invalid-certificate)
- [Download binary stream data from browser using PHP with web service “ downloaded file is corrupted ”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17145651/download-binary-stream-data-from-browser-using-php-with-web-service-downloaded?lq=1)
- [suitable output of hexdump in bash to be input of hex2bin function in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17250895/suitable-output-of-hexdump-in-bash-to-be-input-of-hex2bin-function-in-php)

How to convert a (complete) p12/pfx certificate to receive it in web service and redirects it to PJP page which I download it in there to browser.
I used `xxd` , `hexdump` and `od`.

Yet couldn't optimize the output of these commands to make it's appropriate input for hex2bin function in PHP to get the binary back to download the certificate.

Comment: I'm a little unsure what you're trying to accomplish. Are you trying to pass the certificate through exactly how it's stored on the filesystem? If that's the case [fpassthru](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php) is usually considered binary safe. Not sure what good that does you, though, unless the goal is to just distribute the p12 certs through a web interface (which is why I was unsure if this is what you wanted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution is to remove spaces of the output of bash 
in bash :

```
res=`xxd -p $exportedkey`
echo "${res//[[:space:]]/}"
```

in php :

```
$hex = hex2bin($result);
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=hex.pfx");
header('Content-Length: '.  strlen($hex));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');

echo $hex;
exit();
```

Comment: Ah, I wrote my comment before seeing that this answer was your follow up. It looks like you pretty much figured it out, except fpassthru makes the bash and hex2bin stuff irrelevant.